# Java regular expression for extracting the data between tags

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to a regular expression which extracs the data from a string like

```
<B Att="text">Test</B><C>Test1</C>
```

The extracted output needs to be Test and Test1. This is what I have done till now:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = "<B>Test</B>";
        String reg = "<.*?>(.*)<\\/.*?>";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(reg);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        while(m.find())
        {
            String s1 = m.group();
            System.out.println(s1);
        }
    }
}
```

But this is producing the result `<B>Test</B>`. Can anybody point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use an XML parser?

Comment: I don't have an complex XML file. These are nodes without any child nodes (i.e. flat structure). So I thought regex is good enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three problems:

- Your test string is incorrect.
- You need a non-greedy modifier in the group.
- You need to specify which group you want (group 1).

Try this:

```
String s = "<B Att=\"text\">Test</B><C>Test1</C>"; // <-- Fix 1
String reg = "<.*?>(.*?)</.*?>";                   // <-- Fix 2
// ...
String s1 = m.group(1);                            // <-- Fix 3
```

You also don't need to escape a forward slash, so I removed that.

See it running on [ideone](http://ideone.com/HNcc6).

(Also, don't use regular expressions to parse HTML - use an HTML parser.)

Comment: Thanks..but this produces the output `<B Att="text">Test</B>` for first iteration and `<C>Test1</C>`during second iteration. But I want only `Test` and `Test1` as output.

Comment: @Asha: String s1 = m.group(**1**);

Comment: Working fine now..I had tried it before but gave the index as 0. Didn't realize it is starting from 1.

Comment: @Asha: Group 0 means the entire match.

Answer (score 2):

If u are using eclipse there is nice plugin that will help you check your regular expression without writing any class to check it.
Here is link:
http://regex-util.sourceforge.net/update/
You will need to show view by choosing Window -> Show View -> Other, and than Regex Util

I hope it will help you fighting with regular expressions

Answer (score 1):

It almost looks like you're trying to use regex on XML and/or HTML.  I'd suggest not using regex and instead creating a parser or lexer to handle this type of arrangement.

Answer (score 1):

I think the bestway to handle and get value of `XML` nodes is just treating it as an `XML`.

If you really want to stick to `regex` try:

```
<B[^>]*>(.+?)</B\s*>
```

understanding that you will get always the value of `B` tag.

Or if you want the value of any tag you will be using something like:

```
<.*?>(.*?)</.*?>
```